# PoE cable defective?

Tags: layer1, cable, cabling, power-over-ethernet, utp

Need some expert advice..

So some time ago I got water damage, my PoE switch was completely flooded. 
Since then, I noticed that I could not rotate my cameras anymore via Blue Iris (IP Cam soft), and I could not login anymore.

I had two Huissun (low budget cameras), so I though they were just fried. I bought another PoE camera (SD49225T-HN). On my test stand, the camera worked perfectly.

Today, I mounted the camera to the wall outside, and it has the same problem as my Huissun. Can't rotate and can't login, but I get visual via Blue Iris.
Could this really be the cable that is screwed or something else? I am clueless, and if it's the cable I'm really screwed..

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your cabling got wet in the flood, there is a strong possibility that it is ruined. Indoor UTP cabling is *not* waterproof, and it can easily be damaged by moisture. Water changes the dielectric properties of the cabling, and modern networking uses very high frequencies that need strict tolerances.

Other than that, your applications, consumer-grade devices, and host configurations are all off-topic here.